# Reading a nfc message from tag when user scans an nfc

Tags: android, nfc

**I need to open my app and read the nfc message in the same time when user scans the nfc tags..**

**Currently i am able to open my when user taps or scans the nfc but i couldnt read the data in the nfc at the same time .**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
```

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";
private TextView mTextView;
// private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
protected PendingIntent nfcPendingIntent;
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
IntentFilter[] readTagFilters;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Tag detectedTag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    detectedTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    readTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected, filter2 };
    Log.d(TAG, "ok" + getIntent().getAction());


}

public void enableForegroundMode() {
    Log.d(TAG, "enableForegroundMode");
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED); 
    Log.d("done ", "in " + tagDetected.getAction(0));
    IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent,readTagFilters, null);
    Intent ndefDetected = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    Tag tag = ndefDetected.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    Parcelable[] rawMsgs = ndefDetected .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    if (rawMsgs != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume1");

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume2");
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();
    if (NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this) != null)
        NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setIntent(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "NewIntent is ...." + intent.getAction() + "....."
            + NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    getTagMsg(intent);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return true;
}

public void getTagMsg(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getTagContent" + intent.getAction() + "....."
            + NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Log.d(TAG, "New Intent/1");
        NdefMessage[] messages = null;
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
                .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            messages = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            Log.d(TAG, "New Intent/2:" + messages);
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
        if (messages[0] != null) {
            String result = "";
            byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
            // this assumes that we get back am SOH followed by host/code
            for (int b = 0; b < payload.length; b++) { // skip SOH
                result += (char) payload[b];
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "New Intent/3:" + result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Tag Contains " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are not really doing anything when your activity is started. You should call `getTagMsg` on the tag you grab from the `Intent` in your activity's `onCreate`. Towards the end of the method, simply call `getTagMsg(detectedTag)`.

You should probably have a helper method that starts from an `Intent`, grabs the parceable extra, and reads the contents of the tag from it. You could then use this method both in `onCreate` and `onNewIntent`.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions but when i used the below code in oncreate i am getting a null value .why is this ?,               detectedTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG); Log.d("detected tag", ""+detectedTag);

Comment: Your activity may be started using different types of Intents. It *may* be the NFC one, it may also be a regular Intent to just start your activity. You should check the Intent's action before you try to grab the tag. Take a look at the `onNewIntent` method on [my blog post](http://triangle.io/blog/20130909) and add the check you see there for the Intent's action.

Comment: In your case, you want ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED and ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.

Comment: My intention is to start my android app when i scan a nfc tag and get the tag information (FYI : i am not opening my app before scanning )

Comment: when i try to get the intent's action in oncreate i am always getting "android.intent.action.MAIN" instead of "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" when i scan a tag .

Comment: Okay, so you've included the intents you want in the AndroidManifest.xml file, correct? Do you have filters as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#filtering-intents)?

Comment: Yes i do have the intent  filters as defined in that doc ..<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>